# Wordpress plugins - divide in (OOP) Classes

Tags: wordpress

So, i am developing a Plugin, and I am using a main Class so it can be more easily managed:

```
class MyPlugin{
   function __construct(){
      //my add_actions here
      add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'template_redirect'));
   }

   //my_class_methods here
   function template_redirect(){}
}
```

Up until now, this is all working just fine. But as the plot thickens, I need to add more and more complexity in the plugin so I would like to do something like:

- create a new Class Comment
- in MyPlugin's __construct instantiate $comment = new Comment()
- delegate, in my template_redirect(), an action to a method in $comment like:

  add_action('wp_insert_comment', array($this->comment,'wp_insert_comment'));

or:

- create a new Class Comment
- in MyPlugin's __construct instantiate $comment = new Comment()
- in my Class Comment's __construct add the action to it's method `comment_method`:

> ```
> add_action('wp_insert_comment', array($this, 'comment_method'));
> ```

Is this even possible? in either way, my behaviour isn't being called.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you should probably add most actions and filters with the `plugins_loaded` hook rather than using the `template_redirect` hook, which probably is not called at all when a comment is posted (the form goes to wp-comments-post.php, wordpress deals with request, then redirects the user back to the page where the comment form was before the template is needed.)

```
class MyPlugin{
    function __construct(){
        add_action("plugins_loaded", array($this,"_action_plugins_loaded"));
    }
    function _action_plugins_loaded(){
         //add actions & filters here...
    }
 }
```

Comment: for some reason, the page isn't firing the plugins_loaded event. I am running WP 3.2.1, i used wp_loaded, and it suits me fine. thanks once again